# How to get last element in tokenized string in C++ separated by "::"?

Tags: c++

I'm working on C++,

i have one string as follows:

```
string str = "rake::may.chipola::ninbn::myFuntion";
```

How to get last element from above string which is always after the last occurrence of "::"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`std::string::rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) to locate the last occurrence of `::` and use [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the token:

```
// Example without confirming that a '::' exists.
std::string last_element(str.substr(str.rfind("::") + 2));
```

Comment: One word of caution: `rfind` may return `std::string::npos`, which will wrap around when `+ 2` is added. If the input string is `"rake"`, chances are the result of this expression will be `"ake"`. It's rather unfortunate.

Comment: @MatthieuM., I stated in the code snippet that it did not confirm `::` was present. The OP _should_ check that the result of `rfind()` is not `string::npos` and that `rfind() + 2 < str.length()`.

Comment: If you can use `rfind(":") + 1` it will work as `std::string::npos + 1` is `0`.